# SQL Server query with a scalar variable that can be a varchar or uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql-server

The query below has a scalar variable `@LocationID` that can either be a `varchar` or a `uniqueidentifier` depending on the value of the scalar variable `@LimitTo`.

This query worked before the addition of the addition of the lines

```
OR ((@LimitTo = 'Drawing') AND (ba.DrawingGuid = ...
```

`DrawingGuid` is a `Guid` and not text like the other OR statements.

This suggests that the SQL is analyzed and selects a single conversion method ahead of running the query, and seeing that there are two possibilities, throws the following error when I use `@LocationID` as a `Varchar` (it works fine if `@LocationID` is a `uniqueidentifier`)

> Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier

Though, I'm not sure if this theory is correct. Is there a way to have the `@LocationID` variable either be a varchar or uniqueidentifier for this query?

Here's the query:

```
DECLARE @Contract VARCHAR(60);
SET @Contract = 'F8C018CA-A00C-4BB1-B920-D460786F6820';

DECLARE @LimitTo VARCHAR(30);
SET @LimitTo = 'WorkZone';--'Drawing'; 'WorkZone'

DECLARE @LocationID VARCHAR(60);
SET @LocationID = 'North'; --'2FB87868-D5D7-4A84-916F-F1DEE871A085'; 'North'

SELECT DISTINCT      
    asm.AssemblyCode,
    asm.AssemblyRestorationDesc,
    asm.AssemblyUnit,
    asm.AssemblyGuid,
    (SELECT SUM(m.MarkerQuantity) 
     FROM Marker m 
     WHERE m.AssemblyGuid = asm.AssemblyGuid
       AND m.MarkerExcludeFromScope = 'False'
       AND m.ContractGuid = @Contract
       AND (((@LimitTo = 'WorkZone') AND (m.MarkerWorkZone = @LocationID))
            OR ((@LimitTo = 'WorkRegion') AND (m.MarkerWorkRegion = @LocationID))
            OR ((@LimitTo = 'Drawing') AND (m.DrawingGuid = @LocationID)))
       AND m.Deleted = 0) AS Quantity,
    (SELECT SUM(bm.MarkerQuantity) 
     FROM BaselineMarker bm  
     WHERE bm.AssemblyCode = asm.AssemblyCode
       AND bm.MarkerExcludeFromScope = 'False'
       AND (((@LimitTo = 'WorkZone') AND (bm.MarkerWorkZone = @LocationID))
            OR ((@LimitTo = 'WorkRegion') AND (bm.MarkerWorkRegion = @LocationID))
            OR ((@LimitTo = 'Drawing') AND (bm.DrawingGuid =  @LocationID)))
       AND bm.Deleted = 0) AS BaselineQuantity,
    (SELECT SUM(ba.AllowanceQuantity) 
     FROM BaselineAllowance ba
     WHERE ba.AssemblyCode = asm.AssemblyCode
       AND (((@LimitTo = 'WorkZone') AND (ba.AllowanceWorkZone = @LocationID))
            OR ((@LimitTo = 'WorkRegion') AND (ba.AllowanceWorkRegion = @LocationID))
            OR ((@LimitTo = 'Drawing') AND (ba.DrawingGuid = CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, @LocationID))))
       AND ba.Deleted = 0) AS AllowanceQuantity
FROM 
    Assembly asm
WHERE 
    asm.Deleted = 0
ORDER BY 
    asm.AssemblyCode, asm.AssemblyRestorationDesc, 
    asm.AssemblyUnit, asm.AssemblyGuid
```

Comment: This looks like SQL Server rather than MySQL. Why have you tagged both?

Comment: Removed MySQL tag

Comment: As for the problem, a `uniqueidentifier` is **36** characters in length. Why are you defining your variable as a `varchar` (one only 30 characters in length) and not a `uniqueidentifier`?

Comment: @Larnu I updated the query to have it 60. Good catch. It now works if I use a GUID for LocationID, but not if I use regular text. The updated question states this also.

Comment: Why `varchar(60)`? Why not `uniqueidentifier`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you are trying to do.

You are trying to compare different columns to the `@locationId`, and the column you want to compare depends on the value of `@limitTo`. The other columns (like `AllowanceWorkZone`) are presumably all `varchar`, but in cases where `@limitTo = 'Drawing'` you instead want to compare `@LocationId` with the `DrawingGuid` column, which is a `uniqueidentifier`.

No, you can't do this.

Just declare a second variable which *is* a `uniqueidentifier`, and use that in the comparison against the `DrawingGuid` column...

```sql
declare @LocationVarchar varchar(36) = 'North';
declare @LocationGuid uniqueidentifier = try_cast(@LocationVarchar as uniqueidentifier);
declare @LimitTo varchar(30) = 'foo';

select ...
from   ...
where  (@LimitTo = 'foo' and MyVarcharColumn = @locationVarchar)
       or (@LimitTo = 'bar' and MyGuidColumn = @locationGuid);
```

In the above code, if the incoming filter value is not a valid `uniqueidentifier`, then `@locationGuid` will be `null`, but it won't matter, because the comparison of `MyVarcharColumn` against `@LocationVarchar` is the relevant predicate.

You could of course also use `try_cast` directly in the predicate, but I separated it out to a separate variable just to make it clearer what was going on.

Edit: Without the second variable, it would be...

```sql
where (@limitTo = 'foo' and MyVarcharColumn = @locationVarchar)
      or (@limitTo = 'bar' and MyGuidColumn = try_cast(@locationVarchar as uniqueidentifier);
```

Comment: You answered the basic question as to whether I can do it. In truth, though, I'm testing for an SSRS report and I was hoping to avoid having a separate variable because of how the report works. I'll just need to go to SSRS and see if I can somehow use separate parameters based on the @LimitTo parameter.

Comment: @EdwardBagby I have updated my answer with the code for how it would be done with just a single variable. The key is to use the `try_cast` (or `try_convert`) rather than just `cast` (or `convert`).

Comment: I just saw that and tried it. It worked! Learned something new, thank you!